# Filter data based on group SQL Netezza

Tags: sql, filter, greatest-n-per-group, netezza

Please I have the below table, I need to filter the data based on the **DATE** column,
In the Sus_ID level if the DATE column has NULL get this row or if the hasn't NULL record will get the row for the newest DATE

```
|Sub_ID |Cust_ID    |C_Date    |
|-------+-----------+----------|
|123456 |2233       |2021-02-21|
|123456 |2211       |2021-01-21|
|123456 |3432       |NULL      |
|987654 |1122       |2021-02-21|
|987654 |3322       |2021-01-21|
```

the desired result should be the below

```
|Sub_ID |Cust_ID    |C_Date    |
|-------+-----------+----------|
|123456 |3432       |NULL      |
|987654 |1122       |2021-02-21|
```

I tried the below code but it didn't work

```
    Subs_ID,
    CASE
        WHEN C_Date IS NULL THEN Cust_ID
        ELSE (FIRST_VALUE(Cust_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Subs_ID ORDER BY C_Date DESC )) END AS Cust_ID_N
    FROM
        tbl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netezza supports the SQL Standard `NULLS FIRST` syntax.  I would recommend that you use that:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by sub_id order by c_date desc nulls first) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function with a `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT Subs_ID, Cust_ID, C_Date
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                        PARTITION BY Subs_ID 
                        ORDER BY CASE WHEN C_Date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, C_Date DESC 
                      ) rn
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

The `ORDER BY` clause can be also simplified to:

```
ORDER BY C_Date IS NULL DESC, C_Date DESC
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d064e28074e79a9439d1dff9879556aa) (for MySql but it is standard SQL).
Results:

| Subs_ID | Cust_ID | C_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 3432 | null |
| 987654 | 1122 | 2021-02-21 |

Comment: thanks a lot, @forpas for your great support